# Overloading the stream extraction operator - Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, c-strings, friend-function

trying to overload the extraction operator in this class

```
class Mystring {
    
private:
    
    char* cstring;
    size_t size;

public:

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Mystring &str);
```

the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mystring.h"

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Mystring &obj) {
    char *buff = new char[1000];
    is >> buff;                  /* Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'char *') */
    obj = Mystring{buff};
    delete [] buff;
    return is;
}
```

the error I get is: **Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'char *')**

when I tried to do something like this:
`is >> *buff;`

It reads only the first char

```
Mystring name;
std::cout << "name: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> name;
std::cout << "Your name is " << name;
```

```
name: harry
Your name is h
```

Comment: What compiler and what compiler settings are you using to compile this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the overload reading into a `CharT*`:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits>
basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
  operator>>( basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& st, CharT* s );
```

was removed in C++20. In C++20, the closest you can get is to read into an array of known extent, using the new overload:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits, std::size_t N >
basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
  operator>>( basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& st, CharT (&s)[N] );
```

which in this case could be used by declaring `buff` as an array instead of a pointer:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Mystring& obj) {
    if(char buff[1000]; is >> buff)
        obj = Mystring{buff};
    return is;
}
```

I however suggest that you use a `std::string` instead of this pair:

```cpp
char* cstring;
size_t size;
```

Comment: Oh  thanks I did not know It was removed, I thought it happened because I'm using the Xcode compiler

Comment: I'm still learning so I think it's better for me using c-style string

Comment: @elfaroukkamal You're welcome! If you're using raw owning pointers, be sure to read [The rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score -1):

Well, `istream` formatted input does not support reading strings into `char*` buffers, should it read a single character? a word? a line? everything up to EOF? After all, it doesn't know how large the buffer is.

You should use either

- `read(buffer,count)` to read exactly `count` characters, waiting until they are available or until EOF.
- `auto num_read = readsome(buffer,count)` to read up to `count` characters, without blocking so it might return `num_read<count`.

Comment: `cin` does support reading into a char pointer until C++20: https://wandbox.org/permlink/db46OFwGbGgp7kOq